# After opening a .mpu file in notepad my code no longer can find it inside a zip file

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

```
Sub Unzip2()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim oApp As Object
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
Dim DefPath As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim fileNameInZip As Variant
'direct = "Y:\DataServices\JohnH\MACRO Domestic\AUTO GLS\REAL ZIPS"
zippy = Dir(direct & "\*.zip")
Fname = direct & "\" & zippy


If Fname = False Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    'Root folder for the new folder.
    'You can also use DefPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\"
    'DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    'If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
     '   DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    'End If

    'Create the folder name
    'strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameFolder = direct & "\"

    'Make the normal folder in DefPath
    'MkDir FileNameFolder

    'Extract the files into the newly created folder
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'Change this "*.txt" to extract the files you want
    For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(Fname).Items
        If LCase(fileNameInZip) Like LCase("*.MPU") Then
            oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
                    oApp.Namespace(Fname).Items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
        End If
    Next

   ' MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FSO.DeleteFolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
End If
'direct = "Y:\Excel\EPICAC\NEW FILES\RESULTS\"
MkDir (direct & "\" & "Results")

End Sub
```

I am using the code above in order to extract zips with a .mpu file (which really is just a text file) and then later opening and reading some data out of it.

However, I had to read some data from an MPU in the zip manually today and opened it in notepad. Now when I go into a .zip the file type no longer shows up in the name of the file, and the code does not recognize there are any MPUs in the file.

Is there a way to reverse it so either Windows doesn't remove the .mpu from the file name or a way I can look at file type instead?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by changing the file explorer settings to not hide known file paths.